# How to delete repetitive elements in singly linked list in java?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've implemented my own singly linked list but I have problems with removing repetetive elements I've got in my list.
Here's my implementation:

List.java:

```
public class List {
private Element first;
private int size;

public void removeRepetitive()
{
    Element e1 = first;
    Element e2 = e1.getNext();

    while(e1.getNext() != null && e2.getNext() != null)
    {
        while(e2.getNext() != null)
        {
            if(e1.getCard().equals(e2.getCard()))
            {
                remove(e2.getCard());

            }
            e2 = e2.getNext();
        }
        e1 = e1.getNext();
        e2 = e1.getNext();
    }
}
}
```

Element.java:

```
package lists;

public class Element {
private Karta karta;
private Element next;

public Element(Karta k)
{
    karta = k;
    next = null;
}
public Element(Karta k, Element e)
{
    karta = k;
    next = e;
}
public Karta getCard()
{
    return karta;
}
public Element getNext()
{
    return next;
}
public void setNext(Element e)
{
    next = e;
}
public void setCard(Karta k)
{
    karta = k;
}
```

I managed to write simple removing method but I keep encountering NullPointerException in this example. I've tried everything this is the latest version of my method. Can anyone help me or at least explain how it should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NPE happens when you try to run getNext on a node that you have removed.

Comment: So in the while loop? How should I fix it?

Comment: Think about what is happening. You do an if statement to remove it, then you try to run the getNext method. Inspect a bit more and if you're still having trouble respond again.

Comment: I know that I get this exception when I try to run  e2 = e1.getNext();
But I can't fix it even with if statement

Comment: e1.setNext(e.getNext().getNext()) is the same as deleting e2

Comment: I changed and I don't get any exception but results are wrong.

Comment: I tried also with size but then I get the exception ;(

Comment: Every time you run getNext, what happens? Imagine if you had a method called hasNext, but it's one question per post and I hope I've helped with deleting a node correctly.